# Set d3 y-axis time format with 15 second increments and seconds % 15 == 0?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i'm working on the scatter plot, on the x-axis I have the years value and on the y-axis I have the minutes:seconds values. My question is regarding the y-axis tick format. So, for the y-axis I have as below:

```
//specify format of time to get
const timeSpecifier = "%M:%S";
const times = dataset.map((data) => d3.timeParse(timeSpecifier)(data.Time)); //get values as Date
const yScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([d3.min(times), d3.max(times)]).range([padding, height - padding]);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat((time) => (d3.timeFormat(timeSpecifier)(time)));
```

What I have is as below:

[image]

But what I need is as following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tickValues`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues) to control the axis labeling.

If your data is similar to:

```
const dataset = [
  {Time: "36:12", y: 1994, z: 5},
  {Time: "36:59", y: 1995, z: 5},
  {Time: "37:17", y: 1995, z: 5},
  {Time: "37:23", y: 1995, z: 5},
  {Time: "37:38", y: 1994, z: 5},
  {Time: "38:12", y: 1996, z: 5},
  {Time: "38:33", y: 1995, z: 5},
  {Time: "38:38", y: 1996, z: 5},
  {Time: "38:39", y: 1996, z: 5},
  {Time: "39:14", y: 1996, z: 5},
  {Time: "39:21", y: 1995, z: 5},
  {Time: "39:59", y: 1995, z: 5}
];
```

Use a function taking a min/ max of `Date`s and return 15s increments - the `% 15` clause is within there. You can pass `d3.extent(times)` to that function.

```
const regularLabels = (timeExtent) => {
  // arr like [min Date, max Date]
  // step in milliseconds
  const step = 1000;
  const labels = [];
  for (const d=timeExtent[0]; d<=timeExtent[1]; d.setTime(d.getTime() + step)) {
    if (d.getSeconds() % 15 == 0) labels.push(d.getTime());
  }
  return labels;
}
```

In this example, I didn't have your original issue of the y-axis labels having ticks on the 9th, 24th, 39th and 54th second. Instead, the axis defaulted to 30-second increments. Setting `tickValues` forces it to 15-second increments:

```js
const padding = 40;
const width = 300;
const height = 480;

const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", width);
  
const dataset = [
  {Time: "36:12", y: 1994, z: 5},
  {Time: "36:59", y: 1995, z: 5},
  {Time: "37:17", y: 1995, z: 5},
  {Time: "37:23", y: 1995, z: 5},
  {Time: "37:38", y: 1994, z: 5},
  {Time: "38:12", y: 1996, z: 5},
  {Time: "38:33", y: 1995, z: 5},
  {Time: "38:38", y: 1996, z: 5},
  {Time: "38:39", y: 1996, z: 5},
  {Time: "39:14", y: 1996, z: 5},
  {Time: "39:21", y: 1995, z: 5},
  {Time: "39:59", y: 1995, z: 5}
];

const regularLabels = (timeExtent) => {
  // arr like [min Date, max Date]
  // step in milliseconds
  const step = 1000;
  const labels = [];
  for (const d=timeExtent[0]; d<=timeExtent[1]; d.setTime(d.getTime() + step)) {
    if (d.getSeconds() % 15 == 0) labels.push(d.getTime());
  }
  return labels;
}

// YOUR CODE /////////////////
//specify format of time to get
const timeSpecifier = "%M:%S";
const times = dataset.map((data) => d3.timeParse(timeSpecifier)(data.Time)); //get values as Date
const yScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([d3.min(times), d3.max(times)]).range([padding, height - padding]);
//add tickValues to your axis with regularLabels function above
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
  .tickValues(regularLabels(d3.extent(times)))
  .tickFormat((time) => (d3.timeFormat(timeSpecifier)(time)));
///////////////////////////////

// rest of graph
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1993, 1997])
  .range([padding, width - padding]);
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(3);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(${0},${height - padding})`).call(xAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(${padding},${0})`).call(yAxis);
svg.append("g")
  .selectAll(".points")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.y))
  .attr("cy", d => yScale(d3.timeParse(timeSpecifier)(d.Time)))
  .attr("r", d => d.z)
  .attr("fill", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```